# How to get data from a select statement when using PHP Text DB API?

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I am using this php text database api from [here](http://www.c-worker.ch/txtdbapi/index_eng.php#Lizenz) and I am having trouble with the select statement. I have created a database and a table and I can successfully insert into it using

```
$db->executeQuery("CREATE TABLE people (id inc DEFAULT 0, phone_number int)");
$db->executeQuery("INSERT INTO people VALUES ('123')");
```

but when I try the select statement

```
echo $db->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM people");
```

nothing happens. Does anyone know why I am not able to retrieve anything?

Also how do I create an auto incrementing column? Currently the `id` column stays at value 0 for each insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you bothered to read the manual? This page tells you how to retrieve data using a SELECT query: [Tutorial 1: Use the txt-db-api](http://www.c-worker.ch/txtdbapi/manual_html_eng/examples/tut1.html)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But how do I create a table where the primary key column auto increments by 1 every time I insert a new value? My code above didn't work...

Comment: In most DB systems, your query would give an error! Your INSERT statement gives only 1 value and does not specify that you only want to put it into one field of your table. I have pointed you to the manual, If you read it it will tell you what you want to do. After you have read it, if you are still having trouble then come back and ask again. This site is not here to read the manual for you!

Comment: I did read it but it doesn't give an example for an auto incrementing column. I saw the section http://www.c-worker.ch/txtdbapi/manual_html_eng/sql_limit.html about the auto increment in the create table section, but that's what I did and it didn't work. Also I didn't include the first value for the insert call because you don't need it if it auto increments.

Comment: You cannot invent your own syntax. If you do not tell th equery what columns you want to put values in, how is it going to know?

Comment: but I tried `$db->executeQuery("INSERT INTO people VALUES (0, '123')");` as well, but the auto increment still doesn't work...

Comment: Did you try $db->executeQuery("INSERT INTO people (phone_number) VALUES (123)");

Comment: I just downloaded it and looked at the examples it shipped with and lo and behold there is an example of using INSERTs with auto increment tables. Now if I could manage to open the example file, so could you.